# Match voice and different instruments in a composition

Tags: composition, orchestration

I'm trying to learn how to compose music. This is what I know so far:

- Music theory
- How to play simple songs made by others on the piano
- How to use various DAWs
- How to come up with lyrics that sound good on their own
- How to come up with a good melody

The problem is I don't know how to put these things together into a full composition. When I come up with good lyrics, I don't know how to come up with a melody that fits those lyrics. When I have a good melody, I don't know how to come up with lyrics that fit that melody. Even just making a melody out of 2 or more instruments usually sounds worse than if I just use a single instrument.

**How can I learn the theory behind putting voice and various instruments together into a composition? I'm interested in any kind of resource: reading, classes, videos, ...**

The advice I found on this so far isn't very helpful:

- "You need the right attitude", "Feel the music", "Hear it in your head and write it down": None of this helps when you have no idea what to do in the first place. I'm not feeling how to solve this and I can't hear the solution in my head.
- "Practice practice practice", "Keep practicing and you will get better": Of course you need to practice, but you can't practice something you don't know how to do in the first place. I don't think inputting random stuff into a DAW will bring me to my goal in my lifetime.
- "Try recreating existing music": That's the most useful piece of advice I heard so far, but on its own it doesn't help either. I recreated a bunch of nice songs in a DAW to the point that my version also sounds great. But this doesn't explain why it sounds great and how I can replicate this for my own compositions.

Comment: Welcome! Just to narrow down the question: orchestration—knowing how to write for various instruments—and setting a text to music (or vice versa) are different skills. You'll get the best answers if you edit your question focus on one of those issues here (and maybe post the other as a separate question). And yes, my answer will similarly start with "focus on one thing at a time"; yes, all these skills interact and work together, but they don't just coalesce simultaneously.

Comment: By the way, one other piece of "miscellaneous" advice right off the bat: have you gotten any kind of mentorship or guidance from anyone else? Yes, there have been self-taught composers, but they're rare compared to the thousands who got years of rigorous training from other composers.